# Jersey Web Application Handling Database Connection

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, connection-pooling

I am currently developing a REST api with Jersey on Tomcat 8. Since I am currently implementing Database Connection Pooling I figured out that my approach of open and close connections is far from good.

I have split my project into 3 packages :

- Resource (example: UserResource.java)
- Model (example: User.java)
- Data (example: UserDAO.java)

In the UserResource I create a UserDAO object and call for example

```
@GET
public List<User> getUsers(){
    return userDAO.getAll()
}
```

in the UserDAO Class I create a new connection in every function, for example:

```
public List<User> getAll(){
    List<User> users;
    Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("my example query");
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    .
    .
    .
    return users;
}
```

ConnectionManager is just used to retrieve a new connection from the Connection Pool.

So everytime I make a call from the Resource to the DAO I have to obtain a connection. I considered getting the connection in the Resource and pass it to the dao in the constructor, but that doesnt seem like a good solution.

I couldn't find any examples on how to manage connections with jersey.